# Vue including global styles without repeating the styles for each component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I have an app and would like to include some global styles that I can use anywhere in the app like this:

```
.btn {
  ...
}
```

In webpack I already have this for `_variables.scss` to include things like `$my-color: $fff` and that is wired up like this in my `loaderOptions`:

```
{
  additionalData: `@import "@/styles/_variables.scss";`
}
```

Obviously for some global styles I could do the same thing, however, this will cause my styles like `.btn` to [load as many times](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/) as components that I have.

Logically it would seem best to just go into my `root` Vue component and add global `<style lang="scss"></style>`.

However, I am upgrading a legacy jQuery app and it is being piecemealed and instead of one root app component, I have several roots for parts that have been converted to Vue. I don't have a central place to load these styles.

For instance I have `searchBar` and `checkout` apps that are instantiated using `Vue.extend` (so they *are* all part of the same instance). There aren't just two apps, there are quite a few. If I include the global styles in the root of any of them it... feels... icky...

Is there any way around this or should I set the global styles in a random app with a `TODO` to refactor once everything is ported over?

Ideally I would do the same thing I'm doing with the `_variables.scss` but having the styles duplicated for each component is a non starter for me.

Comment: Did you try to import in *main.js*?  `import '@/styles/globals.css'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you do not need to worry about how webpacks CSS loaders are working.

You can simply go into your `main.js` and `import '@/styles/globals.scss'` to load the styles globally.